# How can I give resource to Ubuntu for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, resource-limiting

I installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Windows 10 store.
It's good for my task and run well. Thanks you for your job.
But it has just one problem, too slow at all.

How can I give more resource to Ubuntu to make stronger than now?

Comment: This seems like a Windows question. What makes you believe that Windows is somehow throttling the resources it provides to Ubuntu? Does your Windows System Monitor show resources being withheld?

Comment: It's just my guess.
When I watched performance tab on task manager, CPU used 20%, Memory used 70% and server is still slow.
It makes me think OS doesn't use resource much more.